# python doctest: stop example execution and use the resulting context in some shell

Tags: python, doctest

i think there was some directive i could enter in the test that would allow me to run some commands interactively at the point of the directive and then continue the example, but i dont remember what it was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you place a breakpoint in your test to enter the debugger?

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```